# How to upgrade magento 1.4.1.1. to last version?

Tags: upgrade, magento-1.4, ce-1.4.1.1, ce-1.4.2.0

My site was running on magento 1.4.1.1, I upgrade it to magento 1.4.2.0. I need to upgrade to last version of magento, my current version has a lot of modules installed. Could you give me advice how to continue with the upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

Many people are doing upgrade process different ways, But I think this is the best way to do this if you have many customization on the site.

1. Make one clone copy of your database 1.4
2. Extract the latest version of Magento
3. Run the Magento installation
4. Give your database user/password and this give database name of clone database of 1.4
5. Proceed to further installation.
6. When your Magento installation finished, your database upgraded to latest version successfully.
7. Now you will need to take one by one customize and third party module to this latest version of Magento. And if it cause any issue you need to check for the latest version supported module or need to fix so that can work with latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded magento from 1.4 to 1.7.2 before..

You have to follow below steps for upgradation

1. Take database backup of your existing version
2. Now keep database of 1.4.2 and extract version 1.5
3. Now start installing process using database of 1.4.2 which is
   current database
4. You will get errors related to foreign key or tables at the time of
   installing. You have to open sql script and define "SET
   FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;" at the start and "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS =
   1;" at the end.
5. After installation , your database is upgraded with 1.5 version
   Then, you can place your theme and extension one by one
6. Same process you have to do for another version. From 1.5 to 1.6

You will get success in upgradation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are ok to upgrade directly to 1.9.2.2 but you will have to re-do your existing theme and the modules that you have loaded.

Start by doing a database dump of your website from 1.4.2.

```
mysqldump -uuser -p'password' database > databasedump.sql
```

Know extract a fresh version of Magento and run the website against the freshly backed up version of your old site. This will force the database to upgrade to the newest version of Magento.

You will want to start by restoring the database to new blank database then pointing your version of Magento at that database.

```
mysql -uuser -p'password' newdatabase < databasedump.sql
```

Make sure you document any errors you get in this process, you will want to do this more than once.

You will be able to login to you Admin now on your new site. You can see your products, categories, orders, customers etc.

Now you can start to assess all your existing modules. The modules that have an upgrade path you can get from the vendors. Custom modules will have to be re-written.

Finally, look at your theme and start with the new RWD Theme that is built in. You will have to style this new as your old theme most likely is not responsive and will not work with all the new aspects of Magento.

Magento has a great WIKI that describes the process in full here https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Manual+upgrade+using+a+fresh+install+and+new+database